# ASP .NET Datapager and datasource

Tags: asp.net, listview, sqldatasource, datapager

I got problem with `datapager` when `datasource` of `listview` changes.

Example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="filter" runat="server" />
<asp:ListView ID="listview" DataSourceID="datasource" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        ...
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        ...
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:DataPager ID="datapager" PagedControlID="listview" runat="server">
    <Fields>
        <asp:NumericPagerField />
    </Fields>
</asp:DataPager>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="datasource" ConnectionString="..." PageSize="10"
                   SelectCommnad="SELECT * FROM [...] WHERE [...] LIKE @filter"
                   runat="server">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="filter" ControlID="filter"
                              DbType="String" PropertyName="Text" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

`Listview` contains lets say 100 `records` without `filter`. `Datapager` shows `pagenumbers` according to `pagesize`.

Now if I select any page except `1st` and then enter `filter` which returns less pages than currently selected page; `datapager` stays on previously selected page and `listview` shows no records even if there are some.

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Tried `SetPageProperties` if `StartRowIndex` > `TotalRowCount` but it's not working. Not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Guess I figured it out. After several tries; this is finally working.

```
protected void filter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dataPager.SetPageProperties(0, this.Invoices_DataPager.PageSize, false);
    this.listview.DataBind();
}
```

Every time filter changes; datapager is set to very first page. Hope it helps anyone with same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had same issue the way I resolved it :

Adding : AutoPostBack=true to Textbox along with OnTextChanged
And to filter_TextChanged : SetPageProperties(0,PageSize,true)

Hope it helps.